# Getting a camera to Yaw, Pitch and Roll in a proper manner with PyOpenGL?

Tags: python, opengl, matrix, camera

I have been struggling for quite a while now, trying to implement a camera which would rotate freely in any of its own axis (namely when increasing yaw, pitch and roll). I have managed to setup the camera to change its position properly depending on the current forward, right and up vectors, which usually do not mess up (and by usually I mean when I omit roll). Simply put, the camera moves forward, but the problem is when I try rotating the camera, which I do not know how to set up properly.

I spawn a camera to use with this class:

```
import math
import numpy


class Camera:
    def __init__(self, position=(0, 0, 0), pitch=0, yaw=0, roll=0):
        self.position = list(position)
        self.yaw = yaw
        self.pitch = pitch
        self.roll = roll
        self.direction = [0.0, 0.0, -1.0]
        self.right = [1.0, 0.0, 0.0]
        self.up = [0.0, 1.0, 0.0]

    # Calculates where each camera vector (front, right, up) is facing given the current pitch, yaw, roll.
    # The derived vectors are the camera's own coordinate system, while the pitch, yaw and roll are world-based so far.
    def cameraVectors(self):
        x = math.sin(math.radians(self.yaw))*math.cos(math.radians(self.pitch))
        y = math.sin(math.radians(self.pitch))
        z = math.cos(math.radians(self.yaw))*math.cos(math.radians(self.pitch))
        self.direction = [x, y, z]

        x = math.sin(math.radians(self.yaw + 90))*math.cos(math.radians(self.roll))
        y = math.sin(math.radians(self.roll))
        z = math.cos(math.radians(self.yaw + 90))*math.cos(math.radians(self.roll))
        self.right = [x, y, z]

        self.up = numpy.cross(self.direction, self.right)

    # Simply increases the rotation when told to. Stuff below function is irrelevant (maybe) as it works alright.
    def cameraRotate(self, rotX, rotY, rotZ):
        self.yaw += rotX
        self.pitch += rotY
        self.roll += rotZ
        self.cameraVectors()

    def cameraMoveF(self, value):
        self.position[0] += value * self.direction[0]
        self.position[1] += value * self.direction[1]
        self.position[2] += value * self.direction[2]
        self.cameraVectors()

    def cameraMoveB(self, value):
        self.position[0] -= value * self.direction[0]
        self.position[1] -= value * self.direction[1]
        self.position[2] -= value * self.direction[2]
        self.cameraVectors()

    def cameraMoveL(self, value):
        self.position[0] += value * self.right[0]
        self.position[1] += value * self.right[1]
        self.position[2] += value * self.right[2]
        self.cameraVectors()

    def cameraMoveR(self, value):
        self.position[0] -= value * self.right[0]
        self.position[1] -= value * self.right[1]
        self.position[2] -= value * self.right[2]
        self.cameraVectors()

    def cameraMoveU(self, value):
        self.position[0] += value * self.up[0]
        self.position[1] += value * self.up[1]
        self.position[2] += value * self.up[2]
        self.cameraVectors()

    def cameraMoveD(self, value):
        self.position[0] -= value * self.up[0]
        self.position[1] -= value * self.up[1]
        self.position[2] -= value * self.up[2]
        self.cameraVectors()

    def getPosition(self):
        return self.position

    def getDirection(self):
        return self.direction

    def getRight(self):
        return self.right

    def getUp(self):
        return self.up

    def getPitch(self):
        return self.pitch

    def getYaw(self):
        return self.yaw

    def getRoll(self):
        return self.roll
```

And I use this ViewMatrix which I create every frame:

```
def createViewMatrix(eyePos, eyeForward, eyeUp):
    E = numpy.array(eyePos)
    F = numpy.array(eyeForward)
    U = numpy.array(eyeUp)

    F = F/numpy.linalg.norm(F)

    S = numpy.cross(F, U)
    S = S/numpy.linalg.norm(S)

    Uprim = numpy.cross(S, F)

    mat = numpy.zeros(shape=(4, 4))

    mat[0][0] = S[0]
    mat[1][0] = S[1]
    mat[2][0] = S[2]

    mat[0][1] = Uprim[0]
    mat[1][1] = Uprim[1]
    mat[2][1] = Uprim[2]

    mat[0][2] = -F[0]
    mat[1][2] = -F[1]
    mat[2][2] = -F[2]

    mat[3][0] = -numpy.dot(S, E)
    mat[3][1] = -numpy.dot(Uprim, E)
    mat[3][2] = numpy.dot(F, E)

    mat[0][3] = 0.0
    mat[1][3] = 0.0
    mat[2][3] = 0.0
    mat[3][3] = 1.0

    return mat
```

The transformation matrix, projection and view matrix work flawlessly when it comes to rendering the view - all objects render properly, but the problem is that I am struggling with setting up the camera's own coordinate system and to make it roll, pitch and yaw according to its own coordinate system. I am obviously wrong somewhere in the code, but I really do not know where the problem may be. I have put a short video showing how the camera renders the objects in the different camera rotations (Ex. when looking down and I turn right, the camera and its target both rotate according to the world Y-axis, not the camera's as I want and when I roll more weird stuff happens). The axis are represented as squares that are rotated to face the camera.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aBaLkE1cUSo

At first I show normal rotations with yaw and pitch. You can notice how the more I pitch and yaw, the more the rotation becomes into a roll (because the yaw is related to the world coordinate system. Also inverts when the camera flips, obviously). Then I show the roll at around 0:48. At 1:00 I show you how the rolling messes up and the whole scene just weirds out.

Please, if anyone can find where and what I am missing, I would be really happy if you could share your thoughts! I am pulling my hair out and I just cannot find what I am missing. Some people mentioned transforming the camera or something, but I really cannot understand how to do all this and I did refer to a lot of resources...

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end of the day there is no way to make such rotations using the simple Euler rotations I was using. Even by trying to rotate the up, right and forward vector in numerous ways, eventually I resorted to working with Quaternions to achieve my goal. Now the rotations work like a charm!